# How can I check why my android app crash without error

Tags: android

I am facing the problem where my application randomly crash without error after updating photo in firebase storage and trying to navigate to particular fragment. Last thing i got in log:

```
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8287 SIG: 9
```

I don't know how to check what makes application act like that. Could anyone give me advice how to check what is wrong or tell me if this log message has any tip what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that an application breaks without giving a reason, but the reason always exists.

Since you are using Firebase in the project, try connecting Crashlytics to the project (included in the Firebase ecosystem), this is done very quickly and easily and then you will definitely see your error in the Firebase console.

So you can see not only detailed information and error stacktrace for your specific problem, but also crashes of your users including detailed analytical information.

1. Go to the Firebase console.
2. Click on the tab "Crashlytics" tab.
3. Click on the button "Enable Crashlytics".
4. You should update your google-services.json file.

See details info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android)

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much Sir